# How to add time onto one field models

Tags: python, django

I have a completion date it has a date field and I was wondering how can I add time, so the person can choose data and time?
here is my models.py

```
class Job(models.Model):
    completion_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: What's wrong with  `models.TimeField` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use either [TimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#timefield) or [DateTimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield).

Answer (score 2):

simply use models.DateTimeField()